# SSRS Line Graph - EmptyPoint - End plot at end of series

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, graph, reporting

See the attached. I've got an SSRS 2012 line graph comparing registrations in 5 minute intervals year on year, this day versus the same in 2013.

We plot the entire day last year but only want to plot the progress this year up until now().

I have virtually everything working as I need, dealing with empty point average as I wish, expression colouring and what have you.

The problem is I can't seem to end the current year line (blue line) when the series has reached an end (because the rest of the day is yet to occur). I need it to end, to cut off, and not flat line.

Something simple I am missing? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The line chart tries to interpolate values between datapoints, and so will just fill in an infinite horizontal line until it finds a new value and then calculate the correct slope between the two, or just go horizontal to the end of the range.  Populate the rows from now() to 12/31 with zeros in the 2013 series.  You'll see the blue line reach now(), make a vertical drop to 0, and then continue off to the right at that lower level.  The effect would look smarter on a bar chart.  But Line charts like this really aren't meant to compare series data with different ranges like you're trying to do.

Comment: I went at this with a CTE that handles the running total within and ends in the current year as of the most recent 5 minutes.